# When using Cloud Page referencing an HTML Content Block to run SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, content-builder

I was doing some hands-on exercises for learning SSJS using CloudPage calling a HTML content block for my ssjs script.

My question is : When creating a test stub cloudpage to run some ssjs exercises, I dont want to use the root folder of the website to host my exercise web page.

How can I change the actual physical location of the CloudPage within the Marketing Cloud folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

MC Cloudpage isn't designed to build a full website, but the most common use case is to build a landing page.

So what you can do is:

- Copy directly the HTML content block that you want to use for your SSJS exercises to the CloudPage

or

Upload the HTML content to content builder then in the cloudpage:

- Use reference content block (point-and-click)
- Or use AMPscript to render a HTML content block

A sample AMPscript code:

```
%%[

var @contentBlockID
set @contentBlockID = 123 /* Content Builder\Exercise\Banner */

]%%
%%=ContentBlockByID(@contentBlockID)=%%
```

Comment: Specifying a value for site key allowed me to specify a test_random_number as a suffix so the root folder was no longer used as the URL for the landing page I was trying to test. Thanks much.